# Casperjs div "still did not exist" - but it does

Tags: javascript, testing, reactjs, phantomjs, casperjs

I want to set up end-to-end testing of my website using CasperJS (1.1.0-beta5, with PhantomJS 2.1.5). I wrote basic tests that work: everything that I wrote explicitly in "index.html" is found by Casper (title, container div, etc.).

Anything my javascript renders after that is not found (even using `waitForSelector` or `wait`). I am using React.

If I go to the url I give to Casper (localhost), I see everything that must be there, and inspecting the page with dev tools shows that my divs exist. Casper just ignores my Javascript.

*How can I even debug to find out what the problem is ?*

Here is the basic HTML layout:

```
<body>      
    <div id="app-container"></div>  
    <div id="footer"></div>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

App.js inserts a div "#app" in "#app-container".
If I print the DOM that Casper sees with `this.getPageContent()`, I see only the above, and no "#app". If I `capture` a screenshot, I see the footer but the rest of the page is blank:

[image: Screen capture by CasperJS]

Here is the code for my test:

```
casper.test.begin('Webapp basic layout', 6, function suite(test) {  
    casper.start(url, function () {
        test.assertHttpStatus(200);
        test.assertTitle('Varapp browser', '<title> found');
        test.assertExists('#app-container', 'Main app container exists');
        casper.waitForSelector("#app", function() {
            test.assertExists('#app', 'Sub app div exists');
        })
    });
    casper.run(function () {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

And here is the output:

```
# Webapp basic layout
PASS Webapp basic layout (6 tests)
PASS HTTP status code is: 200
PASS <title> found
PASS Main app container exists
FAIL "#app" still did not exist in 5000ms
#    type: uncaughtError
#    file: ...
#    error: "#app" still did not exist in 5000ms
#    stack: not provided
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors. Have you taken screenshots to see if you're on the right page? Is this maybe inside of an iframe?

Comment: I updated with the phantom version. The line with `create` in your example produces `Fatal: you can't override the preconfigured casper instance in a test environment.` If I remove it but leave the other events I see nothing more than before. I do not create any iframe, but I will try a screenshot.

Comment: Just disregard the first line. You already have a `casper` instance injected in the test environment.

Comment: The screenshot shows a blank page and my footer, that is, only what is in index.html.

Comment: blank page means? are you running headless or you can see the page?

Comment: I can see the page on Firefox, Chrome etc, full of content. I added the screen capture by Casper in the question: it displays a white rectangle with the footer at the bottom, according to my html and css, but nothing generated by React.

Comment: It looks like an incompatibility with React. I added <script>{some jQuery code}</script> in index.html and Casper sees the content it generates. I will open an issue on Github.

Comment: The source of the problem actually seems to be PhantomJS' incompatibility with React.